# How to add subject to custom email template in magento 2

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I am trying to add subject to custom email template with bellow but it is not working.

```
<!--@ Your Order No {{trans "%order_number" order_number=$data.order_number}} - Order Shipped  @-->
```

its not working for me while i am getting order_number variables in email template.
anyone can help me regarding this

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--@Subject Your Order No {{trans "%order_number" order_number=$data.order_number}} - Order Shipped  @-->
```

I did not add subject now its working for me